# Breaking a 3GB gz file into chunks

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, file

I have a 3GB gz file that I am trying to break into chunks of smaller files which are not required to be gz (I tried to make files of 10000000 lines, this is not a requirement, the chunks could be of any size), but my method is taking ages to run (about 12 minutes). I have the requirement to not use any library such as Pandas, Spark, etc. I can only use pure Python. I tried profiling my code and the write seems to be the slowest thing. Here's my code :

```
import gzip
import os

class FileSplitter:

    def __init__(self):
        self.parse_args(sys.argv)

    @staticmethod
    def run():
        splitter = FileSplitter()
        #run to split the big file into smaller files
        splitter.split()
    

    def split(self):

        file_number = 1
        line_number = 0

        print("Splitting %s into multiple files with %s lines" % (os.path.join(self.working_dir, self.file_base_name), str(self.split_size)))

        out_file = self.get_new_file(file_number)
        a_file = gzip.open(self.in_file, 'rt')
        t = next(a_file)
        with a_file as f: 
            for line in f:
                out_file.write(line)
                line_number += 1
                if line_number == self.split_size:
                    out_file.close()
                    file_number += 1
                    line_number = 1
                    out_file = self.get_new_file(file_number)

        out_file.close()

        print("Created %s files." % (str(file_number)))

    def get_new_file(self,file_number):
        """return a new file object ready to write to"""
        new_file_name = "%s.%s" % (self.file_base_name, str(file_number))
        new_file_path = os.path.join(self.working_dir, 'pychunks', new_file_name)
        print ("creating file %s" % (new_file_path))
        return open(new_file_path, 'w')

    def parse_args(self,argv):
        """parse args and set up instance variables"""
        try:
            self.split_size = 10000000
            if len(argv) > 2:
                self.split_size = int(argv[2])
            self.file_name = argv[1]
            self.in_file = self.file_name
            self.working_dir = os.getcwd()
            self.file_base_name = os.path.basename(self.file_name)
        except:
            print(self.usage())
            sys.exit(1)

    def usage(self):
        return """
        Split a large file into many smaller files with set number of rows.

        Usage:

            $ python file_splitter.py <file_name> [row_count]

        row_count is optional (default is 1000)"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    FileSplitter.run()
```

To run my code I call a .py file containing this code with the name of my gz file, example : python myprogfile.py test.gz

Would you do that differently? Would you use threading (i tried but I couldn't succeed yet as I don't have experience with that)? What would you change in this code?

I don't know if it is my laptop that's too weak in terms of memory and CPU ...

Comment: How large are the uncompressed files in total? It might be that you are just hitting the write speed of your hard disk.

Comment: In total they're 9Go (17 files of about 580 Mo each)

Comment: You mean 9Gb and 580Mb, right?

Comment: Yes, sorry wrote that in french measures

Comment: A few questions to clarify the requirements the program must implement or the assumptions it is allowed to make. Is the decompressed input file always going to be a text file? Is it a requirement that each of the split files are readable text files as well (given that the command-line argument `row_count` specifies the number of lines per split file)?

Comment: Yes the decompressed input file is always going to be a text file, and no it is not a requirement that the split files are readable text files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the split files do not need to be readable text files, I would read & write in chunks of bytes, not in lines. This should be faster than reading and writing line by line. We can go with a chunk size of 4,096 bytes because 4,096 or 8,192 is a typical block size on most file systems.

Although, I should note that when I tested your script on my system with a 9 GB text file which has 81 characters per line, it took about **73 seconds** to split it into files of 10,000,000 lines each, or about 772 MB per file. The fact that it takes 12 minutes on your laptop likely confirms @Graipher's suspicion that your disk's write speed is the bottleneck here.

Using a refactored version of your script that reads & writes in byte chunks (provided at the end of this review), when I ran it on the same file with `--size 772` (split into files of size 772 MB) it took about **35 seconds**. Still a decent improvement, but I'd be curious to know how it runs on your machine.

To implement this, I personally like having a helper method like the following which tells us the chunk sizes to read/write:

```python
from typing import Iterator

def chunk_sizes(total_bytes: int, chunk_size: int) -> Iterator[int]:
    for _ in range(total_bytes // chunk_size):
        yield chunk_size

    if remaining_bytes := total_bytes % chunk_size:
        yield remaining_bytes
```

For example, `list(chunk_sizes(10000, 4096))` which returns `[4096, 4096, 1808]` would tell us that in order to read 10,000 bytes in 4,096 byte chunks, we should read 4,096 bytes, followed by another 4,096 bytes, followed by 1,808 bytes.

## General review

- There's no reason to have `run()` be a `staticmethod`, and it's weird how `FileSplitter` creates an instance of itself inside this method.

  If you change the top-level invocation to `FileSplitter().run()` then `run()` could be simplified to

  ```python
  def run(self):
      self.split()
  ```

  But if you do that you might as well remove `run()` and make `FileSplitter().split()` the top-level call. My recommendation is to move the contents of `run()` under the `__name__ == "__main__"` guard and then remove `run()` entirely as it's no longer needed.
- Always open files with a `with` block to ensure the file is closed properly.
- I recommend using [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) because you get a lot of stuff for free (input type validations, help/usage message with `-h`, etc.).
- I would move the command-line argument parsing logic out of `FileSplitter`, because it should ideally only have one responsibility: splitting files.
- Specify the exact exception you want to handle with a try-except. [Handling a bare `except` is considered a bad practice](https://www.flake8rules.com/rules/E722.html).
- I wouldn't use `sys.exit` inside methods you might want to test, because it exits the Python interpreter.
- In Python 3, f-strings are a much more legible way of doing string interpolation.

  Before

  ```python
  new_file_name = "%s.%s" % (self.file_base_name, str(file_number))
  ```

  After

  ```python
  new_file_name = f"{self.file_base_name}.{file_number}"
  ```

## Refactored version

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
import gzip
import os
import itertools

from typing import BinaryIO, Iterator

CHUNK_SIZE = 4096  # bytes


def megabytes_to_bytes(megabytes: int) -> int:
    return megabytes * 1024 * 1024


def chunk_sizes(total_bytes: int, chunk_size: int) -> Iterator[int]:
    for _ in range(total_bytes // chunk_size):
        yield chunk_size

    if remaining_bytes := total_bytes % chunk_size:
        yield remaining_bytes


class FileSplitter:
    input_file_path: str
    output_directory: str
    output_file_base_name: str
    split_size: int  # size of each partition, in MB

    def __init__(
        self, input_file_path: str, output_directory: str, split_size: int
    ) -> None:
        self.input_file_path = input_file_path
        self.output_directory = output_directory
        name = os.path.basename(input_file_path)
        name_without_file_extension = os.path.splitext(name)[0]
        self.output_file_base_name = name_without_file_extension
        self.split_size = split_size

    def get_new_file(self, file_number: int) -> BinaryIO:
        new_file_name = f"{self.output_file_base_name}.{file_number}"
        new_file_path = os.path.join(self.output_directory, new_file_name)
        return open(new_file_path, "wb")

    def split(self) -> None:
        bytes_per_file = megabytes_to_bytes(self.split_size)
        os.makedirs(self.output_directory, exist_ok=True)

        with gzip.open(self.input_file_path, mode="rb") as in_file:
            for file_number in itertools.count(start=1, step=1):
                with self.get_new_file(file_number) as out_file:
                    for chunk_size in chunk_sizes(bytes_per_file, CHUNK_SIZE):
                        chunk = in_file.read(chunk_size)
                        # chunk == "" means we finished reading the input file
                        if not chunk:
                            return
                        out_file.write(chunk)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="Read a gzip-compressed file "
        "and split its uncompressed contents into separate files."
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "file_name", help="a gzip-compressed file, e.g. foo.gz"
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--size",
        type=int,
        default=500,
        help="desired size of each partition, in MB",
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()

    output_directory = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "pychunks")
    splitter = FileSplitter(args.file_name, output_directory, args.size)
    splitter.split()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for both the review and your suggestion! This took less than 2 minutes on my laptop, I am very curious about how chunks of bytes instead of lines made this gap of performance between the two programs, also one question that I am curious about too, how many lines does your 9GB file contain? Mine has about 162 000 000 lines, and does yield have any effect on time execution here?

Comment: @AhlamAIS Nice, I'm glad it worked well for you! My 9GB file has 120,795,955 lines. I don't think `yield` has much of an effect on time execution here compared to the original, because in the original it is also iterating in a memory-efficient way (line by line).

Comment: What's the speed with chunk size 1 MB? That's what I usually use and I think 4 KB was slower for me in previous benchmarks.

Comment: @KellyBundy That's a good catch! Yeah a chunk size of 1 MB for me was much faster (~8-9 seconds). I'd imagine the optimal value varies depending on one's system, so a nice enhancement to make to this script would be to allow the user to configure the chunk size to use via a command-line option.

Comment: @Setris I am amazed at the way you have given this review. This comment might be against the rules of Stack Exchange but I would like to thank you for this answer. There was a lot for me to learn from it.

Comment: @JohnDoe Thanks, I'm happy to know that you found it helpful!

Answer (score 2):

> What would you change in this code?

I'd simplify the `split` function. Not counting lines and files myself and opening/closing the output files at different places without a `with` statement. Just always try to read another line and if that succeeds, put it and the next up to `split_size - 1` lines into another output file.

```
    def split(self):
        print("Splitting %s into multiple files with %s lines" % (os.path.join(self.working_dir, self.file_base_name), str(self.split_size)))

        with gzip.open(self.in_file, 'rt') as fin:
            for file_number, line in enumerate(fin, start=1):
                with self.get_new_file(file_number) as fout:
                    fout.write(line)
                    fout.writelines(itertools.islice(fin, self.split_size - 1))

        print("Created %s files." % (str(file_number)))
```

While I do frequently use `f` when I only work on one file, I didn't like the very different names `f` and `out_file`. In such cases I use `fin` and `fout` (and I think that's rather common), so I changed that as well.

I'd probably also change the inner `with` to `with open(...) as fout` and have `get_new_file` return only the filename, not open the file itself. I'd rather keep the `open` in the `with` statement and have `get_new_file` be a function without such side effects. Or if your only reason for having `get_new_file` at all was that you had two places for using it, then now you don't need it anymore and could just build the filename inside the `split` function.

Still unfixed issues in your code:

- While you fixed one `line_number = 1` (from [your original](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66105913/12671057)) to `line_number = 0`, you forgot the other one. This makes your chunks one line too short. Wouldn't happen if you only had one place :-)
- Lacking import of `sys`, causing `NameError: name 'sys' is not defined`.
- Lacking creation of folder `pychunks`. Without that, the user gets a rather confusing traceback and `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/runner/p/pychunks/main.py.gz.1'`.
- `t = next(a_file)` loses the first line, as that is never used. Might be what *you* want, but it's not documented and goes against common sense and the description that *is* there and gets shown when you run the script without arguments. Perhaps if you do want that, make it a command-line argument for skipping the first number of lines, with default `0`.